# Please translate this had written text to English

Tags: translation, korean-to-english, transliteration

[image: hand written letter in Korean to english[1]]please translate to English or anything that is understood it.topic ect...

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm sorry but "translation of big wall of text" type questions are off topic, and this or similar questions might get closed in the future.

Comment: Hi - as per @user17915's comment I've closed this for consistency with our current guidelines (though those are always up for discussion in [meta](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/) ) - glad you got an answer though and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 고난 없이 살 수 있을 때가 과연 올까요?
>
> 이 중요한 질문에 대해 성서에 근거한 대답을 이 간단한 출판물에서 얻으시기 바랍니다.
>
> 그리고 하느님은 왜 고난을 허용하실까요? 라는 답도 얻을 수 있는 성구도 직접 성서에서 찾아 보시기 바랍니다.
>
> 이 출판물 뒷면에 있어요. *phone number*

Roughly translates to:

```
Will there ever be a time when we can live without suffering?

I hope you will get a biblical answer to this important question in this leaflet(publication).

And why does God allow us to suffer? Please take a look at the bible where you can find an answer(scripture) to that question.

It's written on the back of this pamphlet. *phone number*
```